# Sitecore disable session for a specific page

Tags: session-state, shared-session

I have a requirement to disable session in one of the page in my Sitecore (8.2) MVC application. This is because, prevent interactions from recording and creating session objects which is then stored in mongo db. I see someways to disable session using web.config, not sure it will serve my requirement (Haven't tested yet).

```
<location path="mypage">
   <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="false" />
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Information I'm looking for is, is there any recommended way of handling it using inbuilt features of sitecore?

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to disable session to not store a page in Mongo/xDB. Just disable it in the content editor.

Analyze > Attributes > Disable Analytics for this page

[image]